# How to decode bytes to first forward slash?

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto, encryption-symmetric

Hey everyone I'm having a slight issue with some python AES Decryption code I wrote. I'm trying to decrypt two different emails (of different lengths) using PyCryptoDome and AES-256-CBC encryption. My code is below:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import json
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

def decrypt(enc):
    # Get key
    key = base64.b64decode("mybase64key")

    # Load dictionary of Base64 values of the payload to decrypt
    dataDict = json.loads(base64.b64decode(myEncryptedData))

    # Create decrypter with our IV
    decrypter = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, base64.b64decode(dataDict['iv']))

    # Pad and decode data
    data = decrypter.decrypt(pad(base64.b64decode(dataDict['value']), 16))

    # EDIT: PRINTING DATA HERE
    print(data)

    # Works for shorter password
    print(data[:-24].decode())
    # Works for longer password
    print(data.decode())
```

It seems like just a padding issue, but I'm not sure how to go about getting the correct padding size. Both passwords/IV's have the same exact encrypted length, so

```
print(len(dataDict['value']))
```

prints 44 for both emails, and padding it prints 48 for both emails which stops me from getting the padding length since it's the same in all cases.

Using

```
print(len(data))
```

returns the same length value for both emails as well. However, when I just print data, I can see the two emails like so:

```
b'abcdefghijklmnop@gmail.com\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x0f\xef\xe2\xa3\xdd\xH9\x7f\xj4\xwf\x14\x88\xd8(x\x90N'

b'abcd.efghi@myydomain.com\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08y\xg3?\xa0\x1e\xaa`\xc2\x67\xf1i]3\xe1\xa0F'
```

How can I go about just getting the string I can see within the bytes array without knowing the length of the original text? Is there a workaround? The two example byte arrays I provided have the same exact length/format of the emails, just not sure how to deal with this issue.

Comment: How did you encrypt?

Comment: By "first slash" do you mean the leading \ in the `\x06` or `\x08` shown as the contents of the two emails? Neither one of them contains a slash (or backslash if that's what you really meant) character...those two items are single bytes/characters being shown in hexadecimal format.

Comment: I don't see a `/` anywhere.

Comment: @kelalaka openSSL via Laravel Crypt::EncryptString method, but it just uses normal OpenSSL

Comment: @martineau oops definitely meant backslash, and yes the \x06 in the first example and \x08 in the second example

Comment: Pecans: I was going to try to show you how to do it, but the first email value you have in your question is invalid. It gives me a `SyntaxError: (value error) invalid \x escape at position 70`. Same for the second value, with a `SyntaxError: (value error) invalid \x escape at position 57` error. Please [edit] your question and fix them.

Comment: @martineau the examples I posted are just the full output of printing the data in my code, I updated my original code to show where exactly I'm printing the values I pasted. Not sure why it's invalid for you, If you're using my code, the problem would be that you have to pass in encrypted data which the examples I gave are not encrypted. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Pecans: I don't know what the problem is in that case. I can't run your code since I don't have `Crypto` installed, so adding a `print()` doesn't help (and shouldn't be necessary if what you said in your last comment is true). Regardless, I made a guess and posted it as a possible answer.

Comment: It sems you're padding the ciphertext. Pad before encrypion, unpad after decryption (for CBC and ECB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what the `\x06` or `\x08` mean or signify, but they both happen to not be printable characters (which is why they display in hexadecimal like that). In addition, the values you show for the two email isn't valid Python syntax.

Ignoring that issue, something along these lines might work:

```
import string

# Leaving the invalid '\xH9\x7f\xj4\xwf\x14\x88\xd8(x\x90N' part off.
email1 = b'abcdefghijklmnop@gmail.com\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x0f\xef\xe2\xa3\xdd'

for i, value in enumerate(email1):
    if chr(value) not in string.printable:
        print(i, '\\x{:02x}'.format(value))
        print(email1[:i])  # Show everything up to that point.
        break
else:
    print('all values were printable')
```

Output:

```
26 \x06
b'abcdefghijklmnop@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you forget to unpad, that is your issue.

Depending on how you padded;

```
pad(data_to_pad, block_size, style='pkcs7')
Apply standard padding.
```

Unpad it reversely;

```
unpad(padded_data, block_size, style='pkcs7')
Remove standard padding.
```